# c# Wpf - how can i get listed item(combobox)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SARManagement;Data Source=AIZAZ\SQLEXPRESS");
            con.Open();
            string query = "Select Semester,ID FROM Batch";
            SqlCommand da = con.CreateCommand();
            da.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(da);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Batch");
            Semester.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            Semester.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Semester"].ToString();
            Semester.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ID"].ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }         
    }
private void Semester_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        here how can i get combobox items.. that are listed in combobox as displaymemberpath
    }
```

how do I get combobox items which is retrieved from database as displaymemberpath ... or share another way to retrieve data and insert data as listboxitem

Comment: Have you tried anything? What stumps you? Have you looked around for similar solutions?

Comment: yeah i tried every thing...but there's no any solution to get listed items..

Comment: or share another way to list data as ListBoxItem in the combobox..

Comment: after that i can get easily items..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` should only have a string with the name of the corresponding column. Try this out:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SARManagement;Data Source=AIZAZ\SQLEXPRESS");
        con.Open();
        string query = "Select Semester,ID FROM Batch";
        SqlCommand da = con.CreateCommand();
        da.CommandText = query;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(da);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Batch");
        Semester.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        Semester.DisplayMemberPath = "Semester";
        Semester.SelectedValuePath = "ID";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
    }         
}

private void Semester_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView data = (DataRowView)Semester.SelectedItem;
    string selstr = data["Semester"].ToString();
    int sel = (int)data["ID"];
    MessageBox.Show("ID: " + sel + " Value: " + selstr);
}
```